# How to remove one row of data when running a linear regression in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to run a linear regression and I need to remove one row of data. I am using the dataset `Income Democracy.dta` and I'm trying to remove the Azerbaijan row for a country fixed effects regression. I've played around with the `subset` and `c()` functions but nothing I'm trying is working.
For reference this is how I did it keeping Azerbaijan in:

```
regfe = plm(dem_ind ~ log_gdppc, data = incdem[c("code", "year")])
```

I welcome any help, very new to R.

I have these packages loaded, however some of them are unrelated but I'm not sure what is needed:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(dplyr)
library(miceadds)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(estimatr)
library(Hmisc)
library(plm)
```

I think a comparable example would be running a fixed effects regression using the Grunfeld data set without one of the firms.
e.g. without firm 6.
I've tried something similar to `grunex = subset(Grunfeld - grunfeld$firm == "6")`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please explicitly list all non-base R packages that you are using. What exactly did your attempt to use `subset=` look like?

Comment: I've had a look but I'm not an expert, do my edits help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```r
incdem_subset <- incdem %>%
  filter(country != "Azerbaijan")

regfe = plm(dem_ind ~ log_gdppc, data = incdem_subset)
```